# How to switch between two analog outputs with a digital output?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, analog, counter

I have a circuit with a 74ls93 counter and I want to use one of its outputs to switch between two analog output, i.e., when the output of the counter is HIGH, the output of the circuit must be V1 and when is LOW the output must be V2. V1 and V2 are fixed selected voltages between 0 and 5 V. The output of the circuit (V1 or V2) will be one of the inputs of a microcontroller.

What is the easiest and cheapest way to do this?. I think i need something like an analog multiplexer, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest and probably cheapest solution is to use 1/3 of a [74HCT4053](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4053.pdf), or use a 74HC4053 with a 4.7K pullup resistor on the 74LS output. Connect VEE to GND for this application.

A0 to V2

A1 to V1

AN is the output

S0 is the control input

/E should be grounded (to enable)

Unused inputs S1, S2 should be tied to GND or Vcc, the others can be left floating.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an analog switch like the 4066 and an inverter like the 74LS04.

[image]

As Spehro Pefhany pointed out, pullups are needed to guarantee the outputs of the 74ls93 and 74LS04 are high enough to enable the 4066.

You may have some spare inverters (or NAND or NOR gates, which can easily be made into an inverter) already in your circuit, in which case you wouldn't need an extra 74LS04 IC.

Total cost from Digi-Key for both ICs is about 85¢ in single quantities.

Comment: If you pick an analog mux instead, you can skip the inverter.

Comment: You should really have pullups on both the LS04 and LS93 outputs if you're going to do this. The 4066 needs 3.15V for a guaranteed valid '1' and 74LS only guarantees 2.5V. It will *typically* work, of course. Or use a 74HCT4066 (but I have fears over continued availability of HCT parts).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks, didn't realize I was right on the edge with those values.